count the number of preliminary and final invoices for each customer
I need count the number of preliminary and final invoices for each customer.
I used this query, but the sum is always = 0
SELECT 
    cust,
    SUM(CASE WHEN typ = 'فاتورة عرض' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_preliminary_invoices,
    SUM(CASE WHEN typ = 'فاتورة نهائية' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_final_invoices,
    COUNT(*) AS total_invoices 
FROM 
    dbo.invmang 
GROUP BY 
    cust;



This is the picture of code and the table, I have customers having more than invoice and type for each invoice (preliminary or final).
I am making report for every customer and how many preliminary invoice have and how many final invoice have

please don't post code and example data as image but as text ...

i need to show the result of running code @derpirscher

Do you get anything from SELECT * FROM dbo.invmang WHERE typ = 'فاتورة عرض' OR typ = 'فاتورة نهائية'?

In principle your approach works fine (see this simplified fiddle  where I took the words from your query. So if your code doesn't count correctly, maybe there is a typo in your data or in your queries? Can't verify that, because I can't read that language/characters. It could also be a problem with the collation of the database, so that the comparisons don't work correctly.

solved the problem was that i was working on view table i did create new view and now all work fine
(the typ is Alias get the name from another table (if 0 then فاتورة عرض and if 1 then فاتورة نهائيه)

thank you all :)

Your first count counts the number of "view invoices" which differs from preliminary invoice, so you had a typo in your search. In your sample data there is no match for your second text to count in typ. However, this is not a typo problem, but a data representation problem. You should create a table for typs which will have a field for id and another for text as well as a key. So your records would look like this:
insert into typs(id, label, code)
values
(1, '<arabic text1>', 'PRELIMINARY_INVOICE'),
(2, '<arabic text2>', 'FINAL_INVOICE');

and then you could do something like this:
SELECT 
cust,
SUM(CASE WHEN typs.code = 'PRELIMINARY_INVOICE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_preliminary_invoices,
SUM(CASE WHEN typs.code = 'FINAL_INVOICE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_final_invoices,
COUNT(*) AS total_invoices FROM 
dbo.invmang
join dbo.typs
on dbo.invmang.typ = dbo.typs.id
GROUP BY 
cust;

So in the future whenever you change these labels, you will only change the label in typs and whenever you want to show the text, join typs and get the label. Of course, unfortunately you will need to adjust the data you already have to be changed to numeric and to have the correct data for each and every record.
